# Format command in Perl

Tags: perl

I cannot completely understand how the format named OUT1_TOP is being printed in the outputfile. I can see that there is one call to write function with OUT1 which would print format OUT1 in the outputfile but I don't know how and when OUT1_TOP is being called.

```
open(OUT1,">outputfile");
format OUT1_TOP =

                                                  #         REPORT            #


Date : @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$date
--------------------------------------------------------
Column1           Column1                   Column1     
--------------------------------------------------------
.
format OUT1 =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<  
$C1,$C2,$C3
.

open(FILE,$filename);
while(<FILE>)
{
# if else conditions where C1,C2,C3 are set ;
}
continue
{
 write OUT1;
}
```

***OUTPUT:*** (seen in outputfile)

```
             #         REPORT            #


Date : Friday September 29 14:51:09 BST 2017
--------------------------------------------------------
Column1           Column1                   Column1     
--------------------------------------------------------
AAA1                    21                  30
BBB2                    2                   21

...... and so on
```

Comment: write is actually doing the write to filehandle `OUT1`, which is specified right on top by `open(out,..`. The format funtions actually does the formatting which you see, kind of like an image layout, so basically the fomat layers walk hand in hand with write.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how the format named OUT1_TOP  is printed in the outputfile I understand rest of the code

Comment: @Vicky: I would strongly suggest that you are wasting your time learning about formats. No-one ever uses them in Perl.

Comment: Thanks Dave, are you trying to say that sprintf and printf are alone are better for formatting ?

Comment: @Vicky: Pretty much. Or perhaps a templating engine. Or if you really want something like formats, take a look at [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks Dave , that is really helpful.

Comment: `format` was a good solution for a common programming task from 1987 -- producing reports for dot-matrix printers with a fixed number of lines per page.

Answer (score 1):

From [`perldoc -f write`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#write):

> By default, the top-of-page format is the name of the filehandle with `_TOP` appended

So when you `write` to `OUT1`, the format in `OUT1_TOP` is used at the top of every page.

And to signal boost Dave Cross's comment above:

> @Vicky: I would strongly suggest that you are wasting your time learning about formats. No-one ever uses them in Perl.